# Error in console for not satisfying a condition

Tags: javascript

Write a function called "isOldEnoughToDrive".

Given a number, in this case an age, "isOldEnoughToDrive" returns whether a person of this given age is old enough to legally drive in the United States.

Notes:
* The legal driving age in the United States is 16.

```
var output = isOldEnoughToDrive(22);
console.log(output); // --> true
```

Starter Code :

```
function isOldEnoughToDrive(age) {
  // your code here
}
```

The program I wrote:

```
function isOldEnoughToDrive(age) {
  // your code here
  output = "";
  if(age > 16){
    output = true;
    console.log(output);
  } else {
    output = false;
    console.log(output);
  }
  return output;
}

isOldEnoughToDrive(21);
```

And I am getting the below error:
[image: Here is one of the condition which is not satisfying]

Comment: You really only need `return age >= 16`. You may be running into issues due to using the global variable `output`. If you must use a variable in your function, you should ideally create it local to your function scope using `var output = age >= 16; console.log(output); return output;` Please read this ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: @Phil The test that he failed claims that it doesn't return `true` when age is 21. Why would using a global variable cause that failure?

Comment: @Phil your solution worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar pure speculation but this could be run in a loop and the `output` variable is checked at various places

Comment: @Phil Wouldn't you expect the message saying which test it failed to say something about that, rather than saying that it fails the "should return true if the age is 21" test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this shorter version of your code:

```
function isOldEnoughToDrive(age) {
  return age >= 16;
}
```

Comment: While this will work, it doesn't really explain why his code failed the test "should return true if the age is 21".